# UILabel Display not update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, setneedsdisplay

I want to write some code to make the `UILabel` text updates whenever the text gets changed. I am writing a small demo like:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        [self.Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        [self.Label setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

When I click the button, the label only changes once to 99999, but I expect it to display 99999 times from 0 to 99999. Anyone has an idea why the code is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`setNeedsDisplay` tells the system that your view *wants* to be drawn, but it doesn't force it to happen.  The view will be redrawn on the next draw cycle, which is happening after the `for` loop completes.  If you want all 100,000 changes to be visible, you'll have to delay the label updates by a human-perceptible amount.

Comment: This is correct.  Drawing in iOS doesn't happen in real time.  Drawing happens after your method is finished and you fall into the main loop.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly right. I need to set a delay time of around 0.1s and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, but to elaborate, if you do want to update the content of the label visibly, you can try the following

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        double delayInSeconds = 0.01 * i;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds *     NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
            [self.Label setNeedsDisplay];
        }); 
    }
}
```

For your purposes though, this is probably irrelevant. A more tactile approach would be to store a number of times the button has been pressed in an instance variable, and increment it each time it is touched, and set the label value appropriately.